# Correct way of implementing database-wide functionality

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, coding-style

I'm creating a small website with Django, and I need to calculate statistics with data taken from several tables in the database.

For example (nothing to do with my actual models), for a given user, let's say I want all birthday parties he has attended, and people he spoke with in said parties. For this, I would need a wide query, accessing several tables.

Now, from the object-oriented perspective, it would be great if the `User` class implemented a method that returned that information. From a database model perspective, I don't like at all the idea of adding functionality to a "row instance" that needs to query other tables. I would like to keep all properties and methods in the `Model` classes relevant to that single row, so as to avoid scattering the business logic all over the place.

How should I go about implementing database-wide queries that, from an object-oriented standpoint, belong to a single object? Should I have an external kinda God-object that knows how to collect and organize this information? Or is there a better, more elegant solution?

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12578908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend extending Django's Model-Template-View approach with a controller. I usually have a controller.py within my apps which is the only interface to the data sources. So in your above case I'd have something like `get_all_parties_and_people_for_user(user)`.

This is especially useful when your "data taken from several tables in the database" becomes "data taken from several tables in SEVERAL databases" or even "data taken from various sources, e.g. databases, cache backends, external apis, etc.".

Answer (score 0):

User.get_attended_birthday_parties() or Event.get_attended_parties(user) work fine: it's an interface that makes sense when you use it. Creating an additional "all-purpose" object will not make your code cleaner or easier to maintain.