# Separation of business logic and data access in django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I am writing a project in Django and I see that 80% of the code is in the file `models.py`. This code is confusing and, after a certain time, I cease to understand what is really happening.

Here is what bothers me:

1. I find it ugly that my model level (which was supposed to be
   responsible only for the work with data from a database) is also
   sending email, walking on API to other services, etc.
2. Also, I find it unacceptable to place business logic in the view, because
   this way it becomes difficult to control. For example, in my
   application there are at least three ways to create new
   instances of `User`, but technically it should create them uniformly.
3. I do not always notice when the methods and
   properties of my models become non-deterministic and when they develop
   side effects.

Here is a simple example. At first, the `User` model was like this:

```
class User(db.Models):

    def get_present_name(self):
        return self.name or 'Anonymous'

    def activate(self):
        self.status = 'activated'
        self.save()
```

Over time, it turned into this:

```
class User(db.Models):

    def get_present_name(self): 
        # property became non-deterministic in terms of database
        # data is taken from another service by api
        return remote_api.request_user_name(self.uid) or 'Anonymous' 

    def activate(self):
        # method now has a side effect (send message to user)
        self.status = 'activated'
        self.save()
        send_mail('Your account is activated!', '…', [self.email])
```

What I want is to separate entities in my code:

1. **Database level entities, i.e. database level logic: What kind of data does my application store?**
2. **application level entities, i.e. business level logic: What does my application do?**

What are the good practices to implement such an approach that can be applied in Django?

Comment: Read about signals

Comment: well you removed the tag but you could use DCI to accmplish the seperation of what the system does (the functionality) and what the system is (the data/domain model)

Comment: You propose to implement all the business logic in signal callbacks? Unfortunately, not all of the my application can be linked to events in the database.

Comment: Rune FS, I tried to use the DCI, but it seemed to me that it do not need much for my project: Context, definition of roles as mixin to the objects, etc. There is an easier way of separation "does" and "is"? Could you give a minimal example?

Answer (score 780, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about the difference between the *data model* and the *domain model* – the latter is where you can find the business logic and entities as perceived by your end user, the former is where you actually store your data.

Furthermore, I've interpreted the 3rd part of your question as: how to notice failure to keep these models separate.

These are two very different concepts and it's always hard to keep them separate. However, there are some common patterns and tools that can be used for this purpose.

### About the Domain Model

The first thing you need to recognize is that your domain model is not really about data; it is about *actions* and *questions* such as "activate this user", "deactivate this user", "which users are currently activated?", and "what is this user's name?". In classical terms: it's about *queries* and *commands*.

### Thinking in Commands

Let's start by looking at the commands in your example: "activate this user" and "deactivate this user". The nice thing about commands is that they can easily be expressed by small given-when-then scenario's:

> **given** an inactive user 
> **when** the admin activates this user 
> **then** the user becomes active 
> **and** a confirmation e-mail is sent to the user 
> **and** an entry is added to the system log
> (etc. etc.)

Such scenario's are useful to see how different parts of your infrastructure can be affected by a single command – in this case your database (some kind of 'active' flag), your mail server, your system log, etc.

Such scenario's also really help you in setting up a Test Driven Development environment.

And finally, thinking in commands really helps you create a task-oriented application. Your users will appreciate this :-)

### Expressing Commands

Django provides two easy ways of expressing commands; they are both valid options and it is not unusual to mix the two approaches.

#### The service layer

The *service module* has already been [described by @Hedde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12579490/383793). Here you define a separate module and each command is represented as a function.

**services.py**

```
def activate_user(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    # set active flag
    user.active = True
    user.save()

    # mail user
    send_mail(...)

    # etc etc
```

#### Using forms

The other way is to use a Django Form for each command. I prefer this approach, because it combines multiple closely related aspects:

- execution of the command (what does it do?)
- validation of the command parameters (can it do this?)
- presentation of the command (how can I do this?)

**forms.py**

```
class ActivateUserForm(forms.Form):

    user_id = IntegerField(widget = UsernameSelectWidget, verbose_name="Select a user to activate")
    # the username select widget is not a standard Django widget, I just made it up

    def clean_user_id(self):
        user_id = self.cleaned_data['user_id']
        if User.objects.get(pk=user_id).active:
            raise ValidationError("This user cannot be activated")
        # you can also check authorizations etc. 
        return user_id

    def execute(self):
        """
        This is not a standard method in the forms API; it is intended to replace the 
        'extract-data-from-form-in-view-and-do-stuff' pattern by a more testable pattern. 
        """
        user_id = self.cleaned_data['user_id']

        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

        # set active flag
        user.active = True
        user.save()

        # mail user
        send_mail(...)

        # etc etc
```

### Thinking in Queries

You example did not contain any queries, so I took the liberty of making up a few useful queries. I prefer to use the term "question", but queries is the classical terminology. Interesting queries are: "What is the name of this user?", "Can this user log in?", "Show me a list of deactivated users", and "What is the geographical distribution of deactivated users?"

Before embarking on answering these queries, you should always ask yourself this question, is this:

- a *presentational* query just for my templates, and/or
- a *business logic* query tied to executing my commands, and/or
- a *reporting* query.

Presentational queries are merely made to improve the user interface. The answers to business logic queries directly affect the execution of your commands. Reporting queries are merely for analytical purposes and have looser time constraints. These categories are not mutually exclusive.

The other question is: "do I have complete control over the answers?" For example, when querying the user's name (in this context)  we do not have any control over the outcome, because we rely on an external API.

### Making Queries

The most basic query in Django is the use of the Manager object:

```
User.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Of course, this only works if the data is actually represented in your data model. This is not always the case. In those cases, you can consider the options below.

#### Custom tags and filters

The first alternative is useful for queries that are merely presentational: custom tags and template filters.

**template.html**

```
<h1>Welcome, {{ user|friendly_name }}</h1>
```

**template_tags.py**

```
@register.filter
def friendly_name(user):
    return remote_api.get_cached_name(user.id)
```

#### Query methods

If your query is not merely presentational, you could add queries to your **services.py** (if you are using that), or introduce a **queries.py** module:

**queries.py**

```
def inactive_users():
    return User.objects.filter(active=False)


def users_called_publysher():
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if remote_api.get_cached_name(user.id) == "publysher":
            yield user
```

#### Proxy models

Proxy models are very useful in the context of business logic and reporting. You basically define an enhanced subset of your model. You can override a Manager’s base QuerySet by overriding the [`Manager.get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) method.

**models.py**

```
class InactiveUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = super(InactiveUserManager, self).get_queryset()
        return query_set.filter(active=False)

class InactiveUser(User):
    """
    >>> for user in InactiveUser.objects.all():
    …        assert user.active is False 
    """

    objects = InactiveUserManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

#### Query models

For queries that are inherently complex, but are executed quite often, there is the possibility of query models. A query model is a form of denormalization where relevant data for a single query is stored in a separate model. The trick of course is to keep the denormalized model in sync with the primary model. Query models can only be used if changes are entirely under your control.

**models.py**

```
class InactiveUserDistribution(models.Model):
    country = CharField(max_length=200)
    inactive_user_count = IntegerField(default=0)
```

The first option is to update these models in your commands. This is very useful if these models are only changed by one or two commands.

**forms.py**

```
class ActivateUserForm(forms.Form):
    # see above
   
    def execute(self):
        # see above
        query_model = InactiveUserDistribution.objects.get_or_create(country=user.country)
        query_model.inactive_user_count -= 1
        query_model.save()
```

A better option would be to use custom signals. These signals are of course emitted by your commands. Signals have the advantage that you can keep multiple query models in sync with your original model. Furthermore, signal processing can be offloaded to background tasks, using Celery or similar frameworks.

**signals.py**

```
user_activated = Signal(providing_args = ['user'])
user_deactivated = Signal(providing_args = ['user'])
```

**forms.py**

```
class ActivateUserForm(forms.Form):
    # see above
   
    def execute(self):
        # see above
        user_activated.send_robust(sender=self, user=user)
```

**models.py**

```
class InactiveUserDistribution(models.Model):
    # see above

@receiver(user_activated)
def on_user_activated(sender, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs['user']
        query_model = InactiveUserDistribution.objects.get_or_create(country=user.country)
        query_model.inactive_user_count -= 1
        query_model.save()
```

### Keeping it clean

When using this approach, it becomes ridiculously easy to determine if your code stays clean. Just follow these guidelines:

- Does my model contain methods that do more than managing database state? You should extract a command.
- Does my model contain properties that do not map to database fields? You should extract a query.
- Does my model reference infrastructure that is not my database (such as mail)? You should extract a command.

The same goes for views (because views often suffer from the same problem).

- Does my view actively manage database models? You should extract a command.

### Some References

[Django documentation: proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

[Django documentation: signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

[Architecture: Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

Comment: Very insightful!  One question/issue: these suggestions imply that all the processing is inside a django website.  An alternative architecture is to use django as the web front-end to a backend platform layer (see http://lethain.com/introduction-to-architecting-systems-for-scale/#platform_layer ).  This platform layer allows you to run code outside of the website framework.  The data model, domain model, service layer, etc would all reside in the platform layer.  And, given that this layer is outside of django, one might use SQL Alchemy as the ORM for the platform layer instead of django.

Comment: It's nice to see an answer incorporating DDD into a django-related question. Just because Django employs ActiveRecord for persistence doesn't mean separation of concerns should go out the window. Great answer.

Comment: Where do I put `services.py` file, and how do I access its methods?

Comment: If I want to validate that the looged user is the owner of an object before deleting that object, should I check that in the view or in the form/service module?

Comment: @Ivan: both. It *must* be in the form/service module because it is part of your business constraints. It *should* also be in the view because you should only present actions that users can actually execute.

Comment: Custom manager *methods* are a good way to implement queries: `User.objects.inactive_users()`.  But the proxy model example here IMO leads to incorrect semantics: `u = InactiveUser.objects.all()[0]; u.active = True; u.save()` and yet `isinstance(u, InactiveUser) == True`.  Also I would mention an effective way to maintain a query model in many cases is with a db view.

Comment: Great answer, but I have to say this is mainly CQRS not DDD.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb This is correct. Note that the answer itself only uses the term "Domain Model". I've included the link to DDD not because my answer is DDD, but because that book does a great job in helping you think about domain models.

Comment: I don't understand how you run the 'execute' method of the ActivateUserForm is execute is not part of the Forms API.

Comment: A book came out this year about applying some architectural patterns (a lot of which seem to be DDD patterns), with Flask & Django used as examples. The title is 'Architecture Patterns with Python'. If you want to learn more in depth what a Domain Model would look like, and how you would combine that with the Django ORM (Repository pattern), and more things like that, I highly recommend this book.

Comment: Goodness what a brilliantly full answer to the question. It has helped address a number of concerns I was starting to have around how I structure my application as I have travelled up the Django learning curve and my app has started to become more complex.  I lot of your answer confirms my direction of travel but takes the thinking way beyond where I would have got to with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 188):

I usually implement a service layer in between views and models. This acts like your project's API and gives you a good helicopter view of what is going on. I inherited this practice from a colleague of mine that uses this layering technique a lot with Java projects (JSF), e.g:

**models.py**

```
class Book:
   author = models.ForeignKey(User)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=125)

   class Meta:
       app_label = "library"
```

**services.py**

```
from library.models import Book

def get_books(limit=None, **filters):
    """ simple service function for retrieving books can be widely extended """
    return Book.objects.filter(**filters)[:limit]  # list[:None] will return the entire list
```

**views.py**

```
from library.services import get_books

class BookListView(ListView):
    """ simple view, e.g. implement a _build and _apply filters function """
    queryset = get_books()
```

> Mind you, I usually take models, views and services to module level and
>   separate even further depending on the project's size

Comment: I like the general approach though from my understanding your specific example would usually be implemented as a [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

Comment: @arie not necessarily, perhaps a better example, for a webshop services would include things like generating cart sessions, asynchronous tasks like product ratings calculations, creating and sending emails etcetera

Comment: I like this approach too, coming also fro java. I'm new to python, How would you test  views.py? How would you mock service layer (if, for example, service makes some remote api calls) ?

Comment: Good. The services.py module is a similar application of the Data Access Object pattern

Answer (score 84):

First of all, [Don't repeat yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/).

Then, please be careful not to overengineer, sometimes it is just a waste of time, and makes someone lose focus on what is important. Review the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) from time to time.

**Take a look at active projects**

- more people = more need to organize properly
- the [django repository](https://github.com/django/django) they have a straightforward structure.
- the [pip repository](https://github.com/pypa/pip) they have a straigtforward directory structure.
- the [fabric repository](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) is also a good one to look at.

  - you can place all your models under `yourapp/models/logicalgroup.py`
- e.g `User`, `Group` and related models can go under `yourapp/models/users.py`
- e.g `Poll`, `Question`, `Answer` ... could go under `yourapp/models/polls.py`
- load what you need in `__all__` inside of `yourapp/models/__init__.py`

[**More about MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

- model is your data

  - this includes your actual data
  - this also includes your session / cookie / cache / fs / index data
- user interacts with controller to manipulate the model

  - this could be an API, or a view that saves/updates your data
  - this can be tuned with `request.GET` / `request.POST` ...etc
  - think **paging** or **filtering** too.
- the data updates the view

  - the templates take the data and format it accordingly
  - APIs even w/o templates are part of the view; e.g. `tastypie` or `piston`
  - this should also account for the middleware.

**Take advantage of [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) / [templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)**

- If you need some work to be done for each request, middleware is one way to go.

  - e.g. adding timestamps
  - e.g. updating metrics about page hits
  - e.g. populating a cache
- If you have snippets of code that always reoccur for formatting objects, templatetags are good.

  - e.g. active tab / url breadcrumbs

**Take advantage of [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/)**

- creating `User` can go in a `UserManager(models.Manager)`.
- gory details for instances should go on the `models.Model`.
- gory details for `queryset` could go in a `models.Manager`.
- you might want to create a `User` one at a time, so you may think that it should live on the model itself, but when creating the object, you probably don't have all the details:

Example:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
   def create_user(self, username, ...):
      # plain create
   def create_superuser(self, username, ...):
      # may set is_superuser field.
   def activate(self, username):
      # may use save() and send_mail()
   def activate_in_bulk(self, queryset):
      # may use queryset.update() instead of save()
      # may use send_mass_mail() instead of send_mail()
```

**Make use of forms where possible**

A lot of boilerplate code can be eliminated if you have forms that map to a model. The [`ModelForm documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) is pretty good. Separating code for forms from model code can be good if you have a lot of customization (or sometimes avoid cyclic import errors for more advanced uses).

**Use [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) when possible**

- e.g. `yourapp/management/commands/createsuperuser.py`
- e.g. `yourapp/management/commands/activateinbulk.py`

**if you have business logic, you can separate it out**

- `django.contrib.auth` [uses backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/), just like db has a backend...etc.
- add a `setting` for your business logic (e.g. `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`)
- you could use `django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend`
- you could use `yourapp.backends.remote_api.RemoteUserBackend`
- you could use `yourapp.backends.memcached.RemoteUserBackend`
- delegate the difficult business logic to the backend
- make sure to set the expectation right on the input/output.
- changing business logic is as simple as changing a setting :)

backend example:

```
class User(db.Models):
    def get_present_name(self): 
        # property became not deterministic in terms of database
        # data is taken from another service by api
        return remote_api.request_user_name(self.uid) or 'Anonymous'
```

could become:

```
class User(db.Models):
   def get_present_name(self):
      for backend in get_backends():
         try:
            return backend.get_present_name(self)
         except: # make pylint happy.
            pass
      return None
```

**more about design patterns**

- there's already a good question about [design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606448/python-design-patterns)
- a very [good video about practical design patterns](http://blip.tv/oreilly-promos/practical-python-patterns-3965008)
- django's backends are obvious use of delegation design pattern.

**more about interface boundaries**

- Is the code you want to use really part of the models? -> `yourapp.models`
- Is the code part of business logic? -> `yourapp.vendor`
- Is the code part of generic tools / libs? -> `yourapp.libs`
- Is the code part of business logic libs? -> `yourapp.libs.vendor` or `yourapp.vendor.libs`
- Here is a good one: can you test your code independently?

  - yes, good :)
  - no, you may have an interface problem
  - when there is clear separation, unittest should be a breeze with [the use of mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)
- Is the separation logical?

  - yes, good :)
  - no, you may have trouble testing those logical concepts separately.
- Do you think you will need to refactor when you get 10x more code?

  - yes, no good, no bueno, refactor could be a lot of work
  - no, that's just awesome!

**In short, you could have**

- `yourapp/core/backends.py`
- `yourapp/core/models/__init__.py`
- `yourapp/core/models/users.py`
- `yourapp/core/models/questions.py`
- `yourapp/core/backends.py`
- `yourapp/core/forms.py`
- `yourapp/core/handlers.py`
- `yourapp/core/management/commands/__init__.py`
- `yourapp/core/management/commands/closepolls.py`
- `yourapp/core/management/commands/removeduplicates.py`
- `yourapp/core/middleware.py`
- `yourapp/core/signals.py`
- `yourapp/core/templatetags/__init__.py`
- `yourapp/core/templatetags/polls_extras.py`
- `yourapp/core/views/__init__.py`
- `yourapp/core/views/users.py`
- `yourapp/core/views/questions.py`
- `yourapp/core/signals.py`
- `yourapp/lib/utils.py`
- `yourapp/lib/textanalysis.py`
- `yourapp/lib/ratings.py`
- `yourapp/vendor/backends.py`
- `yourapp/vendor/morebusinesslogic.py`
- `yourapp/vendor/handlers.py`
- `yourapp/vendor/middleware.py`
- `yourapp/vendor/signals.py`
- `yourapp/tests/test_polls.py`
- `yourapp/tests/test_questions.py`
- `yourapp/tests/test_duplicates.py`
- `yourapp/tests/test_ratings.py`

or anything else that helps you; finding the **interfaces you need** and the **boundaries** will help you.

Answer (score 31):

Django employs a slightly modified kind of MVC. There's no concept of a "controller" in Django. The closest proxy is a "view", which tends to cause confusion with MVC converts because in MVC a view is more like Django's "template".

In Django, a "model" is not merely a database abstraction. In some respects, it shares duty with the Django's "view" as the controller of MVC. It holds the entirety of behavior associated with an instance. If that instance needs to interact with an external API as part of it's behavior, then that's still model code. In fact, models aren't required to interact with the database at all, so you could conceivable have models that entirely exist as an interactive layer to an external API. It's a much more free concept of a "model".

Comment: For those interested, there's an [FAQ about MVC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) in the Django docs.

Answer (score 11):

In Django, MVC structure is as Chris Pratt said, different from classical MVC model used in other frameworks, I think the main reason for doing this is avoiding a too strict application structure, like happens in others MVC frameworks like CakePHP.

In Django, MVC was implemented in the following way:

View layer is splitted in two. The views should be used only to manage HTTP requests, they are called and respond to them. Views communicate with the rest of your application (forms, modelforms, custom classes, of in simple cases directly with models).
To create the interface we use Templates. Templates are string-like to Django, it maps a context into them, and this context was communicated to the view by the application (when view asks).

Model layer gives encapsulation, abstraction, validation, intelligence and makes your data object-oriented (they say someday DBMS will also). This doesn't means that you should make huge models.py files (in fact a very good advice is to split your models in different files, put them into a folder called 'models', make an '__init__.py' file into this folder where you import all your models and finally use the attribute 'app_label' of models.Model class). Model should abstract you from operating with data, it will make your application simpler. You should also, if required, create external classes, like "tools" for your models.You can also use heritage in models, setting the 'abstract' attribute of your model's Meta class to 'True'.

Where is the rest? Well, small web applications generally are a sort of an interface to data, in some small program cases using views to query or insert data would be enough. More common cases will use Forms or ModelForms, which are actually "controllers". This is not other than a practical solution to a common problem, and a very fast one. It's what a website use to do.

If Forms are not enogh for you, then you should create your own classes to do the magic, a very good example of this is admin application: you can read ModelAmin code, this actually works as a controller. There is not a standard structure, I suggest you to examine existing Django apps, it depends on each case. This is what Django developers intended, you can add xml parser class, an API connector class, add Celery for performing tasks, twisted for a reactor-based application, use only the ORM, make a web service, modify the admin application and more... It's your responsability to make good quality code, respect MVC philosophy or not, make it module based and creating your own abstraction layers. It's very flexible.

My advice: read as much code as you can, there are lots of django applications around, but don't take them so seriously. Each case is different, patterns and theory helps, but not always, this is an imprecise cience, django just provide you good tools that you can use to aliviate some pains (like admin interface, web form validation, i18n, observer pattern implementation, all the previously mentioned and others), but good designs come from experienced designers.

PS.: use 'User' class from auth application (from standard django), you can make for example user profiles, or at least read its code, it will be useful for your case.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I'd like to offer my solution anyway. It's based on acceptance that model objects too require some additional functionality while it's awkward to place it within the *models.py*. Heavy business logic may be written separately depending on personal taste, but I at least like the model to do everything related to itself. This solution also supports those who like to have all the logic placed within models themselves.

As such, I devised **a hack** that allows me to separate logic from model definitions and still get all the hinting from my IDE.

The advantages should be obvious, but this lists a few that I have observed:

- DB definitions remain just that - no logic "garbage" attached
- Model-related logic is all placed neatly in one place
- All the services (forms, REST, views) have a single access point to logic
- **Best of all:** I did not have to rewrite any code once I realised that my *models.py* became too cluttered and had to separate the logic away. The separation is smooth and iterative: I could do a function at a time or entire class or the entire models.py.

I have been using this with Python 3.4 and greater and Django 1.8 and greater.

app/models.py

```
....
from app.logic.user import UserLogic

class User(models.Model, UserLogic):
    field1 = models.AnyField(....)
    ... field definitions ...
```

app/logic/user.py

```
if False:
    # This allows the IDE to know about the User model and its member fields
    from main.models import User

class UserLogic(object):
    def logic_function(self: 'User'):
        ... code with hinting working normally ...
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to make my IDE (PyCharm in this case) recognise that UserLogic is actually User model. But since this is obviously a hack, I'm quite happy to accept the little nuisance of always specifying type for `self` parameter.

Comment: Actually i see it as an easy to use approach. But i would move final model to another file, and not inherit in models.py. It would be like service.py were clash userlogic+model

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with you. There are a lot of possibilities in django but best place to start is reviewing [Django's design philosophy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/misc/design-philosophies/#design-philosophies).

1. Calling an API from a model property would not be ideal, it seems like it would make more sense to do something like this in the view and possibly create a service layer to keep things dry. If the call to the API is non-blocking and the call is an expensive one, sending the request to a service worker (a worker that consumes from a queue) might make sense.
2. As per Django's design philosophy models encapsulate every aspect of an "object". So all business logic related to that object should live there:

> **Include all relevant domain logic**
>
> Models should encapsulate every aspect of an “object,” following Martin Fowler’s Active Record design pattern.

3. The side effects you describe are apparent, the logic here could be better broken down into Querysets and managers. Here is an example:

   **models.py**

   ```
   import datetime

   from djongo import models
   from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.db import transaction


   class MyUser(models.Model):

       present_name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
       status = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
       last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

       # As mentioned you could put this in a template tag to pull it
       # from cache there. Depending on how it is used, it could be
       # retrieved from within the admin view or from a custom view
       # if that is the only place you will use it.
       #def get_present_name(self):
       #    # property became non-deterministic in terms of database
       #    # data is taken from another service by api
       #    return remote_api.request_user_name(self.uid) or 'Anonymous'

       # Moved to admin as an action
       # def activate(self):
       #     # method now has a side effect (send message to user)
       #     self.status = 'activated'
       #     self.save()
       #     # send email via email service
       #     #send_mail('Your account is activated!', '…', [self.email])

       class Meta:
           ordering = ['-id']  # Needed for DRF pagination

       def __unicode__(self):
           return '{}'.format(self.pk)


   class MyUserRegistrationQuerySet(QuerySet):

       def for_inactive_users(self):
           new_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=3*365)  # 3 Years ago
           return self.filter(last_active__lte=new_date.year)

       def by_user_id(self, user_ids):
           return self.filter(id__in=user_ids)


   class MyUserRegistrationManager(models.Manager):

       def get_query_set(self):
           return MyUserRegistrationQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

       def with_no_activity(self):
           return self.get_query_set().for_inactive_users()
   ```

   **admin.py**

   ```
   # Then in model admin

   class MyUserRegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       actions = (
           'send_welcome_emails',
       )

       def send_activate_emails(self, request, queryset):
           rows_affected = 0
           for obj in queryset:
               with transaction.commit_on_success():
                   # send_email('welcome_email', request, obj) # send email via email service
                   obj.status = 'activated'
                   obj.save()
                   rows_affected += 1

           self.message_user(request, 'sent %d' % rows_affected)

   admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserRegistrationAdmin)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly agree with chosen answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857584/871392), but want to add option in Making Queries section.

One can define QuerySet classes for models for make filter queries and so on. After that you can proxy this queryset class for model's manager, like build-in Manager and QuerySet classes do.

Although, if you had to query several data models to get one domain model, it seems more reasonable to me to put this in separate module like suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Most comprehensive article on the different options with pros and cons:

1. Idea #1: Fat Models
2. Idea #2: Putting Business Logic in Views/Forms
3. Idea #3: Services
4. Idea #4: QuerySets/Managers
5. Conclusion

Source:
https://sunscrapers.com/blog/where-to-put-business-logic-django/

Comment: You should add some explanation.