# Django: separating business logic from view logic

Tags: python, django

possible refenrece: [Separation of business logic and data access in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578908/separation-of-business-logic-and-data-access-in-django)

In my Django app, I am trying to figure out where to include my business logic. The logic does not fit any models(assume it's a one-page app that doesn't have any models) so I want to add a module that holds the logic. For example,

project/app/my_logic.py

```
def calculate(number_one, number_two):
  return number_one + number_two
```

Then, I would use the logic like,

project/app/views.py

```
def index(request):
  number = my_logic.calculate(1, 2) #can I do this?
  return HttpResponse("the number is: %s " % number)
```

Questions:

1. Where is the right place to put `my_logic.py`?
2. Is it conventional?
3. What might be a better way?

*Note: this is how you import your module (if anyone else is trying to figure out how to do it)*

```
project/app/your_module/your_module.py
project/app/your_module/__init__.py
```

from views.py,

```
from app.your_module import your_module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, but if it's a logical unit, then a separate python module would be a good start and you would of course write its own unit tests for it (as opposed to Django's built-in integration tests with TestClient).

If it needs to work within the model, then a property on model would be a better place.

Comment: If I wanted to make it a separate python module, where do I have to place `my_module.py` within the django project directory?

Comment: I would just put it as a new folder inside the app. So app/stats/logic.py. At a later point you could move it to its own python dependency (don't forget to add __init__.py to the folder, so it's importable).

Comment: Then, in `views.py`, I should do `import stats` and use the method like `logic.calculate()`, right? How do I import `stats` package from django shell?

Comment: `Import stats` work, but `stats.my_module.calculate()` raises `module object has no attribute "my_module"` error.

Comment: `from stats import my_module; my_module.calculate()`