# How does requests module work?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm looking at the `requests` module, and I don't understand how the method `requests.get()` can be invoked.

In the root directory of requests module, there is `api.py` module that has method `get(url, **kwargs)`. Then, how come I don't have to do `requests.api.get()` to invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line #60 of [`https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py) should make it clear. Basically the reason you don't have to explicitly import it or declare it is because it's already being abstracted away for you.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. Would you take a look at my comment to the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276927/django-separating-business-logic-from-view-logic/20277065?noredirect=1#comment30249990_20277065 ? I am trying to understand how to use a method defined in my module.

Comment: @MaximusS sorry mate, cannot help you with that one. Not familiar how django loads their modules.

Comment: @MaximusS try their IRC channel, you might get help there. freenode#django