# Django Rest Framework Business Logic

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, business-logic

I am trying to create a backend with **Django Rest Framework** and am trying to determine where to place the business logic. Would it go in the views.py?  I would like to create more complex services than just getting a list of objects or grabbing one specific object. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks. I realize there is a discussion about the business logic in a generic Django project but I am asking specifically about the django rest framework.

Comment: There is already a big discussion about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578908/separation-of-business-logic-and-data-access-in-django

Comment: Yeah I looked at that one but was hoping to ask specifically about the location within django rest framework

Comment: Did you find a good Design Pattern for this one? Thanks

Answer (score 33):

It is more about design patterns rather than Django Rest Framework.

Here are some tips:

- Providing interfaces using REST should not involve any specific code related to data manipulation or business logic.
- Using an MVC approach does not mean that you shouldn't layer your application.
- You should be able to test your business logic without touching the UI at all.
- Some people may suggest putting business logic in models. But I do not agree with them, since Django models are different from domain models and business related tasks such as tax calculation.
- Before getting stuck in MVC, You could read more about [The MVC implemented in MVC three-tier architecture](http://criticaltechnology.blogspot.com/2011/09/mvc-in-three-tier-architecture.html)
- I suggest having a business layer and related apps putting your business logic there.

[image: MVC + three-tier diagram]

Suppose that you have an online coffee shop & you'd like to provide a REST API for ordering coffees.

Here are my suggested code samples:

myapp/views.py:

```
    def order(request, quantity=1):
        # Process the order by calling the mapped method
        order_id = CoffeeShopService.place_order(quantity)
        return HttpResponse({'order_id': order_id, mimetype='application/json')
```

myapp/services.py:

```
    class CoffeeShopService(object):
        @staticmethod
        def place_order(quantity):
           # do the business logic here
           return order_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. But I have another issue by implementing your idea. I'm difficult to standardize my exception handling. As you know in DRF we have `ValidationError`. In viewsets has another exception also in lower lever such us in models has a lot of exception class. The problem is those error handling has different format in API response.

Comment: Exception handling in DRF is a different question which is possible by Custom exception handling. if you search you can find how to or you may ask a separate question

Comment: I've started to code in `Python` with `Django` recently, before I've coded in `Java`/`Spring Boot`. I very agree with your point that declines putting logic inside the `models.py` making it even fatter. And the `services` module is the best place to make some business processes in my opinion. I just get it from `Spring Boot` experience

Answer (score 2):

It is a design patterns Questing in Rest Framework, I guess. Here is a Detailed Overview of how i use Layered Approach in my API build on Rest Framework!

It is a little more layered for the sake of Easy Maintenance and utilizes Design Patterns and GRASP Principal most importantly!

Layered Approach Package Level View

[image]

Further Classification:

[image]
[image]

Now an Example of How I go through Layers:

1. A Request is made to example.com/Customer/profile
   @project/urls.py
   [image]
2. The Request is forwarded to the Respective URL's Layer (@app/urls/Customer_Url)
   [image: The Request is forwarded to the Respective URL's Layer]
3. URL's Pass it to the Respective Viewset
   (@app/Viewsets/Customer_Viewsets/Customer_Signup.py)
   [image]
4. It being a Post Request, (I assume for this Example) is Forwarded to Business Logic Layer
   (@app/BusinessLogicLayer/BLL.py)
   [image]
5. The Business Logic Layer has an Abstract Implementation(Act as Interface of IBLL) and it forwards the request to respective method to check for all my Business Rules! (@app/BusinessLogicLayer/SUB_BLL/Customer/*)
   [image]
6. The Request is then Forwarded to the Data Access Layer which stores the Data of User in Database. and So forth! (@app/DataAccessLayer/DAL.py)

Comment: `Customer_Name is ""` -- this is plain wrong. And generally the code smells. You should use validation frameworks (for example Marshmallow).

Comment: I am basically Setting an Empty String for Handling some of my Custom Things, This API is interacted by a Dozens of Devices!
Also this Code is the Work of my Team Member so he better Justify it, My Main goal is to give the overview of  Layered Archietecture.
i would myself use if not Customer_Name than that :)

Comment: @warvariuc I would really appreciate if you can pick Mistakes in the Archietecture Side as I myself is more focused on using this for a long term, so I would really love to fix my Errors in Archietecture.
Most of All, Thanks Alot :)

Comment: It's difficult to judge about architecture when camel case names are used, repetitive code, wrong low level idioms. Also there is too much info and screenshots instead of text. IMO. Also I see just code and explanations but no description of the design principles used in the code.

Comment: @warvariuc Currently, I am studying Student with just 1 year completed in Software Engineering and have 3 more years to go through :). I support myself till this level :) and would like to learn and Grow more from your knowledge if we can communicate via Email or Skype?

Comment: Yes. You can find me on GitHub.

Comment: This is Great Archietecture, It organizes Stuff. Love the Tier but do you have any idea on Onion Archietecture?

Answer (score -4):

maybe this is a slightly eccentric way, but I think it's quite helpful to wrap the logic into the serializer by adding methods in it.

**For example**

serializer:

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id',
            'total',
            'discount',
        )

    def calculate_discount(self, whatever_params):
        # calculate discount if you need... and return it

    def calculate_tax(self, whatever_params):
        # calculate tax amount if you need...and return it

    def calculate_grand_total(self, whatever_params):
        # calculate grand total if you need and return it

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # You can make an order by applying 
        # some logic in the calculation method.
        # Maybe by adding a bit of the context 
        # you sent as parameters from view.
```

Comment: Even if it possible to do it, I think putting logic into `serializer`s is not obvious and wrong. Since the main idea of serializers is simply to serialize and deserialize data and make some validation staff. It is incorrect in terms of `django` project architecture.