# filter model queryset using with template tag

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is there a way to combine a queryset filter with a `with` template tag?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
   {% with arts=category.articles.all %}
{% else %}
   {% with arts=category.get_active_articles %}
{% endif %}
#other statements
   # Do some more template stuff in for loop
```

Other variations:

```
{% with arts=category.articles.all if self.request.user.is_superuser else category.get_active_articles %}
```

Cant do a custom queryset in the model, since I don't have the request.

Is there a way to get the filtering I need? I'm trying to display different querysets for the superuser / staff and regular users so I can do some updating of states etc without having to go to the admin page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad convention/practice to write logics in `templates`. `Templates` should be passed data and that's it. In your cases you can do this in your `views`.

**app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.models import Category

def articles(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        articles = Category.articles.all()
    else:
        articles = Category.get_active_articles()

    context = {'articles': articles}
    return render(request, 'articles.html', context)
```

**app/templates/articles.html**

```
{% for a in articles %}
    {% a.title %}
    {% a.content %}
{% endfor %}
```

**PS:** Read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578908/separation-of-business-logic-and-data-access-in-django/12857584#12857584) to understand WHAT should exist WHERE.