# Basic Entity Management System

Tags: python, django, oop, design-patterns, django-models

How can I design an Entity Management system in Django which can be able to adapt to any kind of entity with minimal code changes (e.g. a product in a catalog, patient information in healthcare etc.).

1. Adding, removing, modifying the attributes of an entity should be simple
2. It should allow for nested attributes (sub-entities) e.g Patient -> Consulting doctor
3. Each attribute or sub-entity in the entity can have a set of business rules

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the need for a rather standard django app. I would follow their tutorial in order to grasp django and get you started.

In regards to your questions, I've quoted parts and given links to how you can achieve this:

1. ["Adding" (CreateView)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), ["removing" (DeleteView)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView), ["modifying the attributes"(UpdateView)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) of an entity should be
   simple
2. It should allow for ["nested attributes" (models.ForeignKey)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (sub-entities) e.g Patient ->
   Consulting doctor
3. Each attribute or sub-entity in the entity can have a set of
   business rules. (create a 'controller' and call it in overiden methods, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578908/separation-of-business-logic-and-data-access-in-django) answers where to put it perfectly)

Your requirements pretty much define what django does.