# Should I use an internal API in a django project to communicate between apps?

Tags: django

I'm building/managing a django project, with multiple apps inside of it. One stores survey data, and another stores classifiers, that are used to add features to the survey data. For example, Is this survey answer sad? 0/1. This feature will get stored along with the survey data.

We're trying to decide how and where in the app to actually perform this featurization, and I'm being recommended a number of approaches that don't make ANY sense to me, but I'm also not very familiar with django, or more-than-hobby-scale web development, so I wanted to get another opinion.

The data app obviously needs access to the classifiers app, to be able to run the classifiers on the data, and then reinsert the featurized data, but how to get access to the classifiers has become contentious. The obvious approach, to me, is to just import them directly, a la

```
# from inside the Survey App
from ClassifierModels import Classifier
cls = Classifier.where(name='Sad').first() # or whatever, I'm used to flask
data = Survey.where(question='How do you feel?').first()
labels = cls(data.responses)
# etc.
```

However, one of my engineers is saying that this is bad practice, because apps should not import one another's models. And that instead, these two should only communicate via internal APIs, i.e. posting all the data to

```
http://our_website.com/classifiers/sad
```

and getting it back that way.

So, what feels to me like the most pressing question: Why in god's name would anybody do it this way? It seems to me like strictly more code (building and handling requests), strictly less intuitive code, that's more to build, harder to work with, and bafflingly indirect, like mailing a letter to your own house rather than talking to the person who lives there, with you.

But perhaps in easier to answer chunks,

1) Is there REALLY anything the matter with the first, direct, import-other-apps-models approach? (The only answers I've found say 'No!,' but again, this is being pushed by my dev, who does have more industrial experience, so I want to be certain.)

2) What is the actual benefit of doing it via internal API's? (I've asked of course, but only get what feel like theoretical answers, that don't address the concrete concerns, of more and more complicated code for no obvious benefit.)

3) How much do the size of our app, and team, factor into which decision is best? We have about 1.75 developers, and only, even if we're VERY ambitious, FOUR users. (This app is being used internally, to support a consulting business.) So to me, any questions of Best Practices etc. have to factor in that we have tiny teams on both sides, and need something stable, functional, and lean, not something that handles big loads, or is externally secure, or fast, or easily worked on by big teams, etc.

4) What IS the best approach, if NEITHER of these is right?

Comment: your engineer seems to be recommending a microservices type architecture, which is appropriate in some cases but I'm not sure it is here. The reasoning behind microservices is that they can be easily reused across different applications that may need the same resource with little to no effort, so it saves time in the long run if this is something anticipated.  but it may be over engineering in this case.... There are other equally valid architectural methods to accomplish this goal.

Comment: "However, one of my engineers is saying that this is bad practice, because apps should not import one another's models" this is just not true. It's common to import the User model, the ContentType model etc. These are other Django "apps" but that does not mean they need to be separate  microservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not true that apps should not import other apps' models. For a trivial refutation, think about the apps in django.contrib which contain models such as User and ContentType, which are meant to be imported and used by other apps.

That's not to say there aren't good use cases for an internal API. I'm in the planning process of building one myself. But they're really only appropriate if you intend to split the apps up some day into separate services. An internal API on its own doesn't make much sense if you're not in a service-based architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any reason why you should not import an app model from another one. Django itself uses several applications and theirs models internally (like auth and admin). Reading the [applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/) section of documentation we can see that the framework has all the tools to manage multiple applications and their models inside a project.

However it seems quite obvious to me that it would make your code really messy and low-performance to send requests to your applications API.

Without context it's hard to understand why your engineer considers this a bad practice. He was maybe referring to database isolation (thus, see "Working multiple databases" in documentation) or proper code isolation for testing.

Answer (score -1):

It is right to think about decoupling your apps. But I do not think that internal REST API is a good way.

Neither direct import of models, calling queries and updates in another app is a good approach. Every time you use model from another app, you should be careful. I suggest you to try to separate communication between apps to the simple service layer. Than you Survey app do not have to know models structure of Classifier app::

```
# from inside the Survey App
from ClassifierModels.services import get_classifier_cls
cls = get_classifier_cls('Sad')
data = Survey.where(question='How do you feel?').first()
labels = cls(data.responses)
# etc.
```

For more information, you should read this thread [Separation of business logic and data access in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578908/separation-of-business-logic-and-data-access-in-django)

In more general, you should create smaller testable components. Nowadays I am interested in "functional core and imperative shell" paradigm. Try Gary Bernhardt lectures https://gist.github.com/kbilsted/abdc017858cad68c3e7926b03646554e